# Search NSString for a substring from the right side

Tags: string, cocoa, nsstring, substring

I would like to search for a substring in an `NSString`, but from the right to the left ----- `NSString` searches from the left to the right.

I have a silly way to do it but if someone has a clever way, I'll be glad.

Comment: Please share your "silly way" with the community, so we can all benefit from your point of view (plus, it shows research effort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSString rangeOfString:options:` and pass `NSBackwardsSearch` as one of the options.